FAR Manager меняет цвет фона текста
В режиме запуска исполняемого файла ( в данном случае .py) в какой-то момент текст консоли начинает закрашиваться и становится не читаемым.
Отключение плагина FarColor проблему не решило.
Кто может подсказать причину и пути исправления?

